# Unvisible conversion

Tags: c++

I have a class with constructor and overloaded operator:

```
MyInt(std::string);
friend MyInt operator + (const MyInt &a, const MyInt &b);
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const MyInt &value);
```

when i try to call

```
std::cout << my_int + "123";
```

I have an error:

```
no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘MyInt’ and ‘const char [4]’)
```

What should I do to fix it without overloading the class constructor or operator for `const char*`?

Comment: You want to add `template<size_t N> MyInt(const char (&arr)[N])` constructor?

Comment: I need auto conversion from char->std::string->MyInt

Comment: Change `+` to `<<` to solve the cout issue.

Comment: Sorry, C++ does not work this way. C++ allows a maximum of one implicit conversion.

Comment: @ChurkinAleksey The solution given by KamilCuk can do the work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that there are required two user-defined conversions (that is not allowed). The first one converts the string literal to an object of the type std::string. And the second one converts this temporary object of the type std::string to an object of the type MyInt.

You could introduce one more constructor like

```
MyInt( const char * );
```

In this case the operator + will be valid for your expression.

Otherwise you have to write either

```
std::cout << my_int + MyInt( "123" );
```

or

```
std::cout << my_int + std::string( "123" );
```

eliminating one user-defined implicit conversion.

Answer (score 3):

An implicit conversion sequence can have only one user-defined conversion and calling the `std::string` constructor and the `MyInt` constructor are both user-defined conversions.

So you need to provide either of the two as explicit conversions:

```
std::cout << my_int + std::string("123");
```

or

```
std::cout << my_int + MyInt("123");
```

The only alternative is to define a constructor for `MyInt` that takes `const char*` or `const char[N]` directly.

Answer (score 2):

Your call to `operator+` with a string literal as input requires 2 implicit conversions, one from `const char[N]` to a temp `std::string`, and then from that `std::string` to `MyInt`.  The compiler is allowed to perform only 1 conversion during an implicit conversion sequence.

You should change your `MyInt` constructor to take the `std::string` by `const` reference instead of by value, that will allow the compiler to use the temp `std::string` as-is rather than having to make a copy of it:

```cpp
MyInt(const std::string &)
```

But that won't solve the error.  You need to eliminate one of the conversions.  Add another constructor that accepts either `const char[]` or `const char*` as input, eg:

```cpp
template<size_t N>
MyInt(const char (&)[N])
```

```cpp
MyInt(const char *)
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/6qSjB6)